# Application Form control w/record sets

Tags: vb.net, process, controls

I'm in the process of developing a new .NET system.  It has 24 form screens and multiple record sets for the SQL D/B.  I'm looking for specific ways of controlling the screens (I've numbered them and one calls the next) but I'm not sure if just opening a screen over the last one is the right way to do it.  Should I be hiding the old ones or just leaving them under the new ones?  I want to go back to the prior screen when complete with the screen open.

Secondly, with all the record sets needed to populate the screens I have a single connection to the database and multiple record sets.  Not sure how to be sure if a record set is already opened by a prior screen or not.  Or should I close every record set when I leave a screen and reopen if necessary?

These are basic control questions as to how to navigate through the screens and the record sets.

Finally, should I have the one connection opened at the beginning and then only closed at the end?

I know these are probably basic question to the experienced but I'm just a beginner with event driven code.

All help would be appreciated.  Also, I'm not an Object Oriented Programmer but a Procedure programmer so making classes, objects, etc., is not my thing.

Thanks again for all assistance.

Jim R

Comment: You should be creating the new screens and dispose of them when done, hiding and showing them when needed isn't good practice in my opinion. On another note, only open the connection do your work and then close it; never leave it open.

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm looking for specific ways of controlling the screens (I've numbered them and one calls the next) but I'm not sure if just opening a screen over the last one is the right way to do it. Should I be hiding the old ones or just leaving them under the new ones? I want to go back to the prior screen when complete with the screen open.**

- You should in my opinion create the form and dispose of it when done. Creating a screen over another one can get a little disgusting and isn't a good practice. For example: what if you instantiate a screen and on load you are populating data? The issue with this is, you would have to call another function or method to refresh this data OR close this form out and create it again; it's better to close it out and open it when needed as the data may have changed.

> **Secondly, with all the record sets needed to populate the screens I have a single connection to the database and multiple record sets. Not sure how to be sure if a record set is already opened by a prior screen or not. Or should I close every record set when I leave a screen and reopen if necessary?**

- You should have your classes populated by now and know which one's are. These would determine what record sets are in fact populated. When you close/dispose a form (screen) the record set's should be disposed with that class unless you are doing this in another class.

> **Should I have the one connection opened at the beginning and then only closed at the end?**

- As my comment from above, it's a great practice to close the connection at all times, never leave it open. You should open the connection, perform your query and immediately close this connection. I'm not sure if you have a class or not to handle your connections, but I would advise to create one that can handle your connections; opening and closing the connections.

Comment: Thanks Codexer but you are doing what I hoped would not happen.  Class, Objects, etc., I do not understand.  I open a connection at my Login screen and create a recordset with the information entered in that screen.  I then Show the mainmenu screen if all edits pass.  The Login screen is behind the mainmenu screen.  If I close the Login screen the app stops before showing the mainmenu so I left it open but behind.  Same with the screens after I select them from the mainmenu screen.  They sit on top of the mainmenu screen and when closed go back to mainmenu.

Comment: In some cases there can be 4-5 screens on top of each other all the way back to the Login screen.

Comment: You can change when the application closes down no need to keep that login screen open. Go to Properties of your project, then Application and under "Shutdown mode:" select "When last form closes. Also classes and objects are part of programming, you can't get away from them (that's what OOP is about). It's better to start learning about them sooner than later.

Comment: Also I see you are new here; if this has helped please vote and accept if this has helped you.